# Basic active not showing its content

Tags: java, android-studio

I currently have a main basic activity with a FAB that calls another basic activity with a form. When i run the app i get no errors or anything, but nothing shows in the called activity.

---

I'm calling the second activity from my main using this method on FAB click:

```
    public void cadastrar(View view){
        Intent it = new Intent(ActMain.this, ActCadCliente.class);
        startActivity(it);
```

---

Called class

```
public class ActCadCliente extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_cad_cliente);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

---

XML files - Main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActMain">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.OSapp.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.OSapp.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_act_main"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="cadastrar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:tint="@color/white" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

Second Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActCadCliente">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.OSapp.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.OSapp.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/title_activity_act_cad_cliente" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

Second Activity Content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_nome"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:labelFor="@id/txtNome"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtNome"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtNome"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtNome" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRua"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_rua"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtNome"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtNome"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtNome" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtRua"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints="no"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:labelFor="@id/txtRua"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtRua"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtRua"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtRua" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtRua"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtRua"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtRua" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtEmail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtEmail" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTelefone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/lbl_telefone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edtEmail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtEmail"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtEmail" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTelefone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/txtTelefone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtTelefone"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTelefone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried to `include` the layout, and it worked, but only with the forms, when i tried to make a menu the app crashed when calling the second activity.

Comment: You are right about using include, the second problem you described might be harder to solve but that's the actual problem, so maybe ask a new question just about that

Comment: @MerthanE i wasn't sure about include, tks! about the other problem i figured out that navgraph was conflicting with the code since i'm not using fragments.

Comment: I don't currently see how the content could be shown in your xml/code so there needs to be something like include